# Height adjustment when keyboard appears is wrong in react-native android

Tags: android, keyboard, react-native

I am trying to shorten the screen when the keyboard is active. But it always adjust it weirdly in android, it works fine in iOS.
Before keyboard is active:

[image]

After keyboard is active:

[image]

I am using RN 0.37, this also happens when i am starting from scratch:

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  Keyboard,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
var _keyboardWillShowSubscription;
var _keyboardWillHideSubscription;
height = height - 20;

class awesomeproject extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            height: height,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        _keyboardWillShowSubscription = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', (e) => this._keyboardWillShow(e));
        _keyboardWillHideSubscription = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', (e) => this._keyboardWillHide(e));
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        _keyboardWillShowSubscription.remove();
        _keyboardWillHideSubscription.remove();
    }
    _keyboardWillShow(e) {
        this.setState({height: height - e.endCoordinates.height});
    }
    _keyboardWillHide(e) {
        this.setState({height: height});
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{height: this.state.height}}>  
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', flex: 1}} />
            <View style={styles.fieldBox}>
                <TextInput 
                    style={styles.field}
                    placeholder={'hello'}
                    autoCapitalize={'none'}
                    placeholderTextColor={'#afbccc'}
                    blurOnSubmit={false}
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    ref={'textinput'}
                    onChangeText={(data) => this.setState({message: data})} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  field: {
        color:'black',
        fontWeight:'bold',
        fontSize:18,
        flex: 1,
        marginHorizontal: 10
    },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('awesomeproject', () => awesomeproject);
```

Comment: Did u find a solution? keyboard is height more in andoird i think.  i'm experiencing same issue

Answer (score 0):

In andoird the calculated the height is more i think .for my requirement i remove the e.endCorordinaets.height and put it 0.

The view auto resizes in andorid.So u dont know this setState in android. No need to change height in andorid. It will work automatically but i thinku need that to work in ios. so remove changing the height and check whether view is auto resizing.

Remove this

```
 this.setState({height: height - e.endCoordinates.height});
```

Comment: Hi @Vicky , I fixed it by removing all of the keyboard events altogether and adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to my Android Manifest android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml as it only happens on Android.